# What is the point of this "token" in IndexedDB firebase-messaging-store

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, indexeddb

[image: IndexedDb Token for firebase cloud messaging]

---

I am confused, Can i use this token (stored in indexedDb) for subscribe the device to topics or sending push notifications to device ?
What is the point of this token ?

---

Best Regards

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this database is how the Firebase Cloud Messaging client stores the device token. This is however not documented, so you should not rely on this database entry existing.

Instead, if you want to use the token (to subscribe to a topic or for another cause) use the [public API to get the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token):

```
messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
  ...
});
```

The above *may* read the token from the indexeddb, but it may also actively get the token from a call to the FCM servers.

Comment: With much thanks. I am saving that messaging.getToken() returned token. But it refreshes every page postback event. I am using nuxtjs, firebase app initializes every refresh. how can i prevent this behaviour ?

Comment: In general you can't control when FCM generates a device token. But if you think something may be wrong in your code, I recommend opening a new question with the [minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry about that question limits :)

Answer (score 0):

As Frank said,

```
const localStorageKey = 'webpush';
messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
if (localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey) !== currentToken) {
   localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, currentToken); 
}
...
});
```

Firebase stores token in indexed db. When the token refresh IndexedDb will take the updated token.

---

[image: IndexedDb]

---

### [image: LocalStorage]

Theese tokens are exactly same.

---

My token changes because my service worker unregister on every page refresh (in dev. mode it is weird). Then it registering again. So, if service worker status is unregistered firebase going to create new token. But in production mode service workers work well.